# Clojure function call performance

Tags: clojure

If Clojure functions are stored as `vars`, does that mean there's an additional lookup to execute them compared to e.g. static methods in Java?

If so, is there any way of defining a function in Clojure so that it gets called without the performance penalty?  (Or if not, how is that performance penalty avoided?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a var needs to be derefed in order to retrieve the associated function and therefore there is additional overhead (deref,cast,invoke) in comparison to a direct static method invocation.

There is an [open enhancement ticket](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1263) that proposes a change to Clojure itself to improve invocation performance as well as a workaround suggestion further down in the comments.

Comment: Of course this can be mitigated by binding the function locally if it is going to be used frequently in a specific context `(let [bound-f f] ...)`